# PHP DomDocument memory errors when uploading files

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel app I have a textarea, which has a text editor which allows people to upload images. I need to get these images from within the text and save them to the server.

The following code works perfectly for small images, but now I'm trying an image that's only 400k and it's throwing memory errors.

I've tried suppressing errors using many different methods from many different articles and posts, to no avail. Any suggestions on how to get this to stop throwing errors?

```
// $body contains the contents of the POSTed textarea, 
// which includes HTML and images

public function storeImages($body, $article)
{
    $dom = new \DomDocument();
    $dom->loadHtml($body, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

    foreach($images as $img)
    {
        $src = $img->getAttribute('src');

        // if the img source is 'data-url'
        if(preg_match('/data:image/', $src))
        {
            preg_match('/data:image\/(?<mime>.*?)\;/', $src, $groups);
            $mimetype = $groups['mime'];
            $filename = uniqid().'.'.$mimetype;
            $filepath = '/media/'.$article->id.'/'.$filename;
            $image = Image::make($src)
                ->encode($mimetype, 100)
                ->resize(1024, null, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                })
                ->save(config('filesystems.disks.media.root').'/'.$article->id.'/'.$filename);
            $img->removeAttribute('src');
            $img->removeAttribute('style');
            $img->removeAttribute('data-filename');
            $img->setAttribute('src', $filepath);
            $img->setAttribute('class', 'img-responsive');
            $img->setAttribute('alt', '');
        }
    }

    return $dom->saveHTML();
}
```